# Appending and loading a script on click jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I currently have a site I am working on where there is a script that only needs to be loaded and shown when a certain element is clicked.  The script we are loading is external and very slow to load and blocks the dom from loading as fast as it should.  I am looking to append this script or load its contents into a certain element on click.  I have looked high and low and have tried many different methods to do this with no success.  I know this is possible and have done this before but cannot remember how.

Note that I have tried loading the contents of the url into an iframe then cloning and adding to the element.

The code below illustrates what I am looking to do

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var $slowLoadingScript = $('<script src="http://external-slow-script.com/script.js"></script>');      

    $slowLoadingScript.load(function(){
      $("#Element").append(slowLoadingScript);         
    });


  });
```

Note the contents of the script look like this:

```
document.write("a long list of html and js");
```

Comment: I assume you should offcourse be appending this script to head section, right?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev The Script is huge and it is also calling external scripts.  It has jquery UI, scrollTo and a long list of other libraries / plugins.

Comment: how many KB though? Having it load once on first hit and then be cached isn't an option?

Comment: @defau1t - I do not want to append to the head, I need this in the element as listed above.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - The script is 250kb+ It is hard to say there is are 6-8 external files being called (css/js).  The main issue is that it the scripts block the loading of the remaining pieces of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getScript('http://external-slow-script.com/script.js');
});
```

Explanation for jQuery's `$.getScript()` at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/.

Comment: I have tried this method with no success.  When calling .done() it does not give me the data from this script.

Comment: Why do *you* need the data? The JavaScript is executed once loaded.

Comment: I need the contents of this script to execute and be able to append this to a certain element. This is not a library it is an actual widget that I need to render.  $getScript does not work in the ways that I have tried it.

Comment: You could replace `document.write("a long list of html and js");` with `$('#id-of-element').append('a long list of html and js');`.